# viewportを使用したmonacaIDEのライブプレビューの画面サイズ制御

Tags: monaca

monacaIDEで開発を進めています。

iOS,Androidともに画面の横幅を自動調整させたく、
[こちらのページ](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/ja/reference/monaca_api/monaca_viewport/)を参考に下記のように`monaca.viewport`で制御しようとしています。

コードの一部

```
<script>
monaca.viewport({width : "device-width"});
</script>
```

ですが、monacaIDEのライブプレビュー画面では横幅がPC画面の解像度と
一致してしまい、表示がずれてしまいます。

この問題についてよい修正方法をお持ちの方がおられましたらご教授頂きたく存じます。

Answer (score 1):

まず、参考になさっているドキュメントが古いです。
現在のMonacaでは動作しません。
(フレームワークがCordova5のため)
ドキュメントの右上のプルダウンよりバージョンを選択し閲覧してください。
過去バージョンのドキュメントは、
過去バージョンで作成した人のための参考資料となっており、
新規で開発する方向けではありません。

また、MonacaのIDEで表示されるプレビュー画面は
実機で表示される画面と必ずしも同じわけではありません。
ですので、プレビューに対応すると実機で不具合が出る可能性が高いです。
開発環境としては実機にてデバッガーをインストールし確認してはいかがでしょうか？